# batch modify entries spreadsheet - excel libreoffice calc

Tags: excel, batch-processing, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have an .ics file with ~1xx entries, like this. I get it to download, unfortunely now without reminders.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210104
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20210105
DTSTAMP:20211222T103045Z
UID:30706b2bdff036eed10e577b0f609351
CREATED:20210101T090000Z
DESCRIPTION:blue
LAST-MODIFIED:20210101T090000Z
LOCATION:here
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:ocean
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210107
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20210108
DTSTAMP:20211222T103045Z
UID:81b03814a0bb3c6ae442f992b8ca7776
CREATED:20210101T090000Z
DESCRIPTION:green
LAST-MODIFIED:20210101T090000Z
LOCATION:here
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:forest
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

I have to add batch modify entries to add reminders. I assume excel/libre-/open-office should be a good tool? Maybe macros?
So, between "TRANSP" and "VEVENT" I'd like to add something that looks like this:

```
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT12H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

How can I handle that in bulk for all entries? I am a bit familiar with C and bash programming, but no idea about spreadsheets.

Comment: A file editor? like BBedit or Programmera File Editor

Comment: For such a task, you don't require a spreadsheet application. You could do the modifications in a terminal window or a simple text editor that supports search / replace, maybe with regular expressions (npp). Details depend on your OS. If you're using Windows, then it's a PowerShell issue. If you're using Linux, you could use awk / sed to modify the input file. Do you need to insert the same four lines for every entry, or do you need different reminders?

Comment: No different reminders, the same 4 lines for every entry. Never used sed but awk. It probably has got many more functions than for what I know.

Comment: Ok, same 4 lines - that's easy. Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1236/9558 - it offers a sed and a perl command as template. Are you familiar with regex? You'll need one that replaces every TRANSP:TRANSPARENT \n END:VEVENT with the same values and additionally the VALARM. You'll need to add the line breaks using \n and make sure that your regex isn't greedy, otherwise your resulting ics file will be much shorter than expected (create a backup first!). If you're unsure, you should open a new question, since the issue doesn't concern spreadsheet applications.

Comment: Yes, indeed, to confess I'm unsure, but thanks anyway.